# Замена протокола у внутренних ссылок с http и https

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-воспроизведено

Если кто-то разместил в сообщении ссылку на этот сайт с протоколом https, а переходящий по ссылке человек в данный момент находится на странице с http, то браузер будет ругаться и потере безопасного соединения.
Вот ссылки, кому хочется попробовать:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/

**Предлагаю**:
Показывать внутренние ссылки, ведущие на этот сайт тем кто переходит по ним с http указывать как http, независимо от протокола, который был указан в разметке. Ну и с https то же самое.

Comment: FYI http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

на *https*-запрос выдаётся сертификат, не содержащий `*.ru.stackoverflow.com`.

думаю, это временно, до генерации нового сертификата, и обходных путей не требует.

**обновлено**

но обратить внимание администраторов на то, что неплохо бы добавить `*.ru.stackoverflow.com` (или хотя бы `meta.ru.stackoverflow.com`) в сертификат, мне кажется, стоит.

Comment: Не подумал об этом, но в любом случае количество сообществ постоянно растет и это было бы хорошим фиксом проблемы перехода между протоколами для любого нового сообщества.

Answer (score 4):

Надо просто ставить два слеша вместо протокола, чтобы браузер его сохранял.

Вероятно, если человек уже на сайте по протоколу https, то проблем с сертификатом у него нет.